# git folder is listed locally but not on remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've a folder on my local branch(-es) under `packages/producer-iframe` (e.g. in branch "dev-master"). Unfortunately this folder doesn't exist on my remote branch (e.g. "origin/dev-master").

I've tried to rename/relocate the folder, committed and pushed again. Nothing worked.

I've also tried to create a new branch, added the specific files but this also didn't work.

How can I add this folder to my remote branches?

Edit: the folder is not empty. it contains other folders and files.

Edit: We use tags/versions to handle our production system. The strange thing is, that this folder was released on version before (and was working). Now, one release later it "disappeared" from the dev-master branch.

Comment: Does the folder have any files in it?

Comment: Yes, files and sub-directories

Comment: Do you have a .gitignore file excluding that folder?

Comment: Branches don't contain files directly: they point to one commit and thereby contain all the history from that last commit on backwards. The *commits* hold files. Each commit holds a full and complete snapshot of all of its files. Inspect the contents of any given commit to see what files it has using, e.g., `git ls-tree -r <hash>`.

Comment: @guenni_90 no, they aren't ignored.

Comment: If you create f1 and add x.txt to it and commit and push can you see it? Can you see any of your local changes in the remote?

Answer (score 1):

Git only tracks files. It does not track folders. So if you have an empty folder in your local working directory, you cannot add it to git. You need to add some files to the folder first and commit those.

Comment: The folder is not empty. It has several files and folders in it

Comment: @Brotzka Did you commit those files to git? Did you push that commit to your remote? How are you inspecting the remote branch to determine if it contains the files in this folder?

Comment: I browse the repository directly on bitbucket. And yes, these files have been committed. We use tags/versions to handle our production system. The strange thing is, that this folder was released on version before (and was working).

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to have `packages` folder in `.gitignore`

If this is your case you can modify you're .gitignore in two ways:

- Remove `packages` line
- Add `!packages/producer-iframe` (git >= 2.9)

Comment: But all other packages within the package folder are in git. `producer-iframe` is only one of 8 subfolders and the other seven are "working"

Comment: This could still happen if they were added forcibly or before .gitignore was added.